# Why does `Table` returns values but `Plot` doesn't plot them?

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

The `Table` function works fine and return a nice list of values

```
n = 200000`200;
k = 2 n - 50`200;
\[Mu] = 10`200^-5;
\[Nu] = 10`200^-5;
qhat = k/(2 n);

Table[Log[(
  E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 4 n \[Nu]))/
  NIntegrate[
   E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 
       4 n \[Nu]), {qhat, 1/(4 n + 1), 1 - 1/(4 n + 1)}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 12]], {s, 0, 1, 0.01}]
```

but the `Plot` function shows an empty plot.

```
Plot[Log[(
  E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 4 n \[Nu]))/
  NIntegrate[
   E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 
       4 n \[Nu]), {qhat, 1/(4 n + 1), 1 - 1/(4 n + 1)}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 12]], {s, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "P(qhat | s)"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Why?

Comment: what version are you running? It works fine on the latest sources.

Comment: Version 10.0.1.0 (Mac OSX). I tried to restart the Kernel and to restart Mathematica but it still does not work. Can you really see the function on the plot? Note that other plots work fine for me. For example `Plot[2 x^2, {x, 0, 1}]` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

as I can see the problem is that in NIntegrate `s` is localised. define a function for your expression

```
f[s_] := Log[(E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 
    4 n \[Nu]))/NIntegrate[E^(4 n qhat s) (1 - qhat)^(-1 + 4 n \[Mu]) qhat^(-1 + 
    4 n \[Nu]), {qhat, 1/(4 n + 1), 1 - 1/(4 n + 1)}, MaxRecursion -> 12]]
```

and then the plot works normally

```
Plot[f[s], {s, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "P(qhat | s)"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It is the solution indeed! Thanks. +1. Can you tell me a bit more of why this happens? Why is `s` localized in the `Plot` case but not in the `Table` case? And what does it exactly mean? Does it mean that in the `Plot` case `s`has no value associated to it in the `NIntegrate` function? Why does it work using a function?

Comment: I just can suppose that it happens becouse of NIntegrate can't process undefined variables like "s". It contributes all the vars to be numerically defined or to be integrating parameters. If you try to evaluate NIntegrate expression separately you will see the message of non-numerick evaluation

Comment: the difference between Table and Plot looks like Table firstly defines the list of "s" values and then calculates expression on this list, but Plot works inside some another way